# Dynamic list of urls in Twirl/Play

Tags: scala, url, playframework, twirl

I'm trying to create a dynamic list of URLs in Twirl template with Play with no luck. I can't seem to map over a collection to create list of URLs for some reason. This is what I have:

```
@casesCollection.map(e => {
   <td><a href="/cases/@{e.get._id}/Search">@e.name</a></td>
})
```

The part within the href does not compile. Any ideas how this issue can be solved?

Comment: what is `casesCollection`? what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You've not given enough details about the type of `casesCollection` and the error you're getting.

Here's a simplified example that works:

In the controller:

```
def index = Action {
    val casesCollection = List("A", "B", "C")
    Ok(views.html.xxx(casesCollection))
}
```

The view `xxx.scala.html`:

```
@(casesCollection: List[String])
<ul>
@casesCollection.map { e =>
    <li>@e</li>
}
</ul>
```

In my example `casesCollection` is a simple `List` of `String`s. You may have a list of some sort of objects, but it should be easy to adapt.